# Find min(A)+max(A)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $A=\int^1_0|t^{2021}-x^{2021}|dt,\;x\in [0,1]$ .Then $max(A)+min(A)=$

(A) $2$

(B) $1$

(C)$1-\frac{1}{2022\cdot2^{2021}}$

(D) $1-\frac{1}{2^{2021}}$

(E) $\frac{2021}{2022}$

I find that $max (A)= 1-\frac{1}{2022}$ for $x=1$ and tried to find $min(A)$ calculating the integral for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and I get that $min (A)=0.$

So the answer is E but my teacher said that it is not corect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when we fix $x$, the expression of $A$ can't be zero since $t^{2021}$ is not a constant.

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 |t^{2021}-x^{2021}|\, dx &= \int_0^x (x^{2021}-t^{2021})\, dt + \int_x^1 (t^{2021}-x^{2021})\, dt\\
&= x^{2022}-\frac{x^{2022}}{2022} + \frac{1-x^{2022}}{2022} - x^{2021}(1-x)\\
&= 2\cdot x^{2022}-x^{2021 } + \frac{1-2\cdot x^{2022}}{2022} \\
&=\frac{1+4042\cdot x^{2022}}{2022} - x^{2021}
\end{align}

Differentiating it and equate it to $0$:

$$4042x^{2021}-2021x^{2020}=0$$

$$x(2x-1)=0$$

Its value when $x = 0$ is $\frac1{2022}$.

If $x=\frac12$, the smallest $A$ is

\begin{align}\frac{1+4042\left( \frac12\right)^{2022}}{2022}-\frac1{2^{2021}}&=\frac1{2022}+\frac{2021}{2022}\left( \frac12\right)^{2021}-\frac1{2^{2021}}\\&=\frac1{2022}-\frac{1}{2022}\left( \frac12\right)^{2021}\\&<\frac1{2022} \end{align}

$$\min(A) + \max(A) = 1-\frac{1}{2022}\left( \frac12\right)^{2021}$$